# What is the ideal set-up for Adobe AIR , Flash/ActionScript and SQLite development?

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, ide, air, flash-cs5

I am getting into ActionScript-ing and SQLLite development.

What are the essential development IDEs and utility tools I should get set up for a smooth development experience?
It would be great if you categorize - as free and paid-for-software.

I am accustomed with the  Microsoft "free" experience in terms of  - Visual Studio Express edition or SQL Server Express edition.

Are there similar counter parts for this platform?

Answer (score 1):

FlashDevelop - Open source IDE for flash but no visual designer. As far as SQLLite you can actually create and manage the databases all with actionscript but if you want to edit/create them with an IDE there are several open/free solutions, from a quick google search we have:

//SQLLite DB manager/admin tool made in Adobe AIR
http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58

//Same idea but open source made with QT so probably C/C++
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

//FlashDevelop
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page

Flashdevelop is pretty much king when it comes to code hinting/completion, pretty much what you'd expect in features from microsoft VS IDEs. There is also a pretty good user base and thus many tutorials/documentation and project templates.

Answer (score 0):

I too use the DB admin tool formerly from www.dehats.com, which has since been renamed Lita and put on [GitHub](https://github.com/probertson/Lita) . However, a significant drawback to Lita is its complete lack of runtime error reporting when executing SQL queries.

Mauricio Piacentini is an excellent programmer, but Flash developers should be aware that his 
SQLite Database Browser does not support the non-standard features added to AIR's version of SQLite, such as additional column affinity types.

So, as a complement to Lita I've been using Paul Robertson's [Run!](http://probertson.com/projects/run-air-sqlite-query-testing-tool/) app. It doesn't have as many features as Lita, but it supports AIR's version of SQLite and it does report errors in your SQL queries.

Like Ascension, I'm a fan of FlashDevelop.